# Do I still need to use .Open() and .Close() if I already use using statement in C#?

Tags: npgsql

I'm new with Npgsql, my C# Code like below:

Do I still need to use:

conn.Open();
conn.Close();

if I already use using statement?, I have try to remove it but nothing happen.

```
        try
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Models.AppSettings.PG_SQL.Connection_String))
            {
                conn.Open();  // do I still need this?, I remove it, but it still working properly

                try
                {
                   string sql = "Select * From mytable1"

                    using (var dr = conn.ExecuteReader(sql, new { } ))
                    {
                        if (dr.Read())
                        {
                            // do some process
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Helper.SaveLogAsync("Learning.Test: " + e.ToString(), Models.Errs.ErrType.Err);
                }
                finally { }

                conn.Close(); // do I still need this?, I remove it, but it still working properly
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helper.SaveLogAsync("Learning.Test: " + e.ToString(), Models.Errs.ErrType.Err);
        }
        finally { }
```

Comment: Fortunately NpgSql is open source, and you can [check the source code](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/d024d51e885190c227826980abb63c64d6e383fa/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnection.cs#L949) to see what it does when you open and close the connection. Don't forget, the ability to dig into things is at your fingertips when working with open source software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can safely remove `conn.Open()` and `conn.Close()` when using a `using` statement in C#. The using statement ensures that the `Dispose()` method is called on the `NpgsqlConnection` object when the block is exited, which takes care of closing the connection.

Your code without `conn.Open()` and `conn.Close()` calls:

```cs
try
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Models.AppSettings.PG_SQL.Connection_String))
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "Select * From mytable1";

            using (var dr = conn.ExecuteReader(sql, new { }))
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    // do some process
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helper.SaveLogAsync("Learning.Test: " + e.ToString(), Models.Errs.ErrType.Err);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Helper.SaveLogAsync("Learning.Test: " + e.ToString(), Models.Errs.ErrType.Err);
}
```

In this case, you don't need to explicitly call `conn.Open()` because the `ExecuteReader` method will automatically open the connection if it's not already open. Similarly, you don't need to call `conn.Close()` because the `using` statement takes care of disposing the connection, which includes closing it.